# Post the code in the user comment

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Hi I am new member to this site. Can anyone please explain how to post the code in this site?

Comment: No actually my doubt is how to post the code as a reply to one user?

Comment: @user1626972 Are you asking how to comment? You seem to already know how, although you don't have enough rep to comment on other people's questions. If you're asking how to format code in comments, the linked post covers it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Ok I got it.Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 1):

See this:
[image]

Comment: No actually my doubt is how to post the code as a reply to one user?

Comment: Hope you got it now

Comment: And if your question is about how to put code in comment, you dont have enough rep to comment and moreover you cant get the formatting right in a comment

Comment: Ok I got it.Thanks for your response. :)